# use='literal' in WSDL binding (input & output) -> issue while accessing through SOAP UI

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have WSDL defined and tested with my business logic and found to be working fine. When I tried to import the WSDL in SOAP UI / access WSDL endpoint via browser, I get following message:

> Request Message type information has multiple parts than one single wrapped complexType. Use WRAPPED/LITERAL if interoping with some other soap stack becomes a problem

What could be the possible issue?

I have deployed the application in Tomcat server and it uses Apache axis for hosting web service. Also noted that, if the header WSDL PART is removed from WSDL MESSAGE this issue does not occur.

Comment: did you translate the (error-) message from an other language into English? if so, you should mention that. it seems like bad English/sentences that do not make sense.

Comment: @hoijui This is the message printed on the console while consuming WSDL endpoint via browser / SOAP UI. Message is not translated.

Comment: We would probably need your WSDL file to check out. Or May be the header. Wouldn't be able to help with this error message.